# HttpClient exception when using .Net standard 2.0 library with UWP application

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

I am using a .Net standard library 2.0 which talks to a REST endpoint using `HttpClient` POST. I am using `client.SendAsync` with `HttpRequestMessage` and awaiting the call. The library is referenced in a UWP app and i am invoking the POST method to get response from REST endpoint.

I am always getting following exception and have not been able to find any clues or any details about this error. Please note that the machine where i am running this is in network and i am able to hit the REST endpoint via browser. Also UWP app has all necessary capabilities(internet,client/server) enabled.

Using Visual studio 2017 with OS target version 16299 Build(Fall creators update)

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Exception Details:

```
ex = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
A connection with the server could not be established
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
  ... at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.d__111.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown - --
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
  at HttpTest.Client.d__11.MoveNext()
```

Thank you,
Akshay.

Comment: Code formatting for readability

Comment: Provide code as [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It turned out to be OS issue- didn't go in detail to find root cause- but same code is working fine on another win 10 RS3 box.

Comment: What's your project's target version? Have you also tried to enable the `Private Networks(Client&Server)`